# When activating a child theme, what core settings have to be reset ie; Custom Menus etc?

Tags: child-theme

When activating a child them I often have to reset custom menus. The menus themselves are still created but just have to be activated again. Is there a list of settings which are often unset when a child theme is activated? This isn't about theme settings, but core settings in WordPress

Comment: What child theme? What parent? I don't use parent/child themes that much but I don't recall having this issue.

Comment: @s_ha_dum none specific, I was curious if anyone knew of a list of common settings which don't stay set when activating a child theme. Custom menus are an example, if a child them is using a parent theme's settings menu locations etc, it'd be ideal if

Comment: ... ideal if... ?

Comment: Are you expecting child themes to honor the menu/configuration setting of the parent?

Comment: It would be ideal if a child theme is activated to have the settings remain in place.

Answer (score 0):

Switching theme does not purposely perform any forcible changes to configuration (that I can think of).

The changes that are typically observed are caused by mismatch in theme's features, for example menu locations and sidebars are likely differently named. So items assigned to them get treated as assigned to invalid location (which they are in current theme).

Comment: i'm saying though if I create a child theme of the currently activated theme. Activating the child theme would mean there are no new menu locations or sidebar locations. They would be the same named locations coming from the parent theme template files. This is assuming my child theme simply has a style.css to begin with.

Comment: @Anagio : you are making some big assumptions. Child themes can be very different from the parent.

Comment: I'm talking only about a single style sheet not making changes to template files just the simple part of activating a child theme with a style sheet